# Can I create a single code from data entered in an issue tracker in sharepoint 365?

Tags: issue-tracking

I have created a basic issue tracker in SharePoint office 365. The reporter describes characteristics of the issue using drop down menus in an issue entry form (possible responses highlighted blue). The responses relate to Process impacted, issue type, impacted departments (Highlighted green). Based on the response to these questions I wish to create a single code summarising these issue characteristics using the bracketed values. [image]

If in the example above the issue related to contract execution delay due to a dispute in the legal department the code would be as follows;

07-04-03

if the finance department were also impacted the number would be 07-04-03-02.

Is it possible to generate such a code automatically within the list?

Answer (score 3):

I assume these are single choice columns and that the numbers are always in the form `(##)`. If so, you can create a code using a calculated column using a formula like this:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT([Process%20Impacted],3),2)&"-"&RIGHT(LEFT([Issue%20Type],3),2)&"-"&RIGHT(LEFT([Impacted%20Department%201],3),2)&IF(ISBLANK([Impacted%20Department%202]),"","-"&RIGHT(LEFT([Impacted%20Department%202],3),2))
```

Just replace the columns above with the actual internal name of your column. Only the last one is conditional based on your example above, but you could easily make them all conditional as needed.

Additional formulas and details can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct. I will check whether this works tomorrow and let you know. Many thanks for the response!

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you but this worked perfectly. Many thanks!